# Can someone please explain how they got the formula for the longitude!??

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

[image]

Why is the longitude equation given as a constant rate of increase $u(\phi)=c\phi$, and why can't we simply do the same for $v(\theta)$ then? i.e., $v(\theta)=d\theta$ for some constant $d>0$.

Comment: Because you have $\Delta u=c\Delta \phi $ then $\dfrac {du}{d\phi } =c$ integrate the differential equation $u(\phi)=c\phi +C$ and $u(0)=0$